# Fetch duplicate rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

```
Col1 | Col2
2    | jim
2    | jam
3    | raw
3    | cooked
3    | boiled
5    | none
6    | yum
```

So in this table I want to fetch records which have multiple value in col1 like:

```
Col1 | Col2
2    | jim
2    | jam
3    | raw
3    | cooked
3    | boiled
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, an alternative to using `EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from <table> t
   cross apply (select 1 ex
                from <table> t2 
                where t2.Col1=t.Col1 
                group by t2.Col1 
                having count(t2.Col1) > 1) tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2 
              where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 <> t.col2
             );
```

Comment: @Divya it would be nice to pick a correct answer, since other people who later find your question, will know what is the correct answer (or the one that helped you move in the right direction).

Comment: this is the answer that worked for me.. @RaduGheorghiu

Comment: @Divya Then, the right option is to mark it as correct :) Under the upvote/downvote arrow, there's a check-mark which you can click, which will turn into green, marking the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
select *
from t
where col1 in
( select col1
  from t
  group by col1
  having count(*) > 1
)
```